# check if the page print has been printed and then close it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to check if the page has been printed and then close it.
I searched a lot but there is no answer
I tried:

```
1- window.matchMedia('print')  but it return always false.
2-window.onafterprint it doesn't work anymore.
```

3- I can not create a new doc and insert body of my page in it because my page comes from Crystelreport and it does have a barcode.

My code is simple:

```
var win = window.open(url, 'popup', 'toolbar = no, status = no, scrollbars = yes, resizable = yes');
win.onafterprint = function () {
                                    win.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var win = window.open(url, 'popup', 'toolbar = no, status = no, scrollbars = yes, resizable = yes');
win.onafterprint = function (e) {
    e.target.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Farai, it did not work at all, even it did not reach the fire point.
The problem is more complex because is related to browser options and Chrome it blocked this option, I send the question to google but they did not answer.
There is way to catch the content of the page and then create your own page, in this case your answer could work, but I don't to do that because it is difficult when you use crystel report and when you page has barcode.